# How to have users enter a formatted date in wicket?

Tags: date, wicket, user-input

I am using wicket and eclipse and trying to create a text box to have users enter a date that will format itself (i.e. user pushes keys "20130607" and in the text box they will see "2013-06-07") I've tried

```
...
private DateTextField <String> EffectiveDateStart;
private DateTextField <String> EffectiveDateEnd;
...
EffectiveDateStart = new DateTextField<String>("EffectiveDateStart","yyyy.MM.dd");
EffectiveDateEnd = new DateTextField<String>("EffectiveDateEnd","yyyy.MM.dd");
...
myForm.add(EffectiveDateStart);
myForm.add(EffectiveDateEnd);
...
```

And when I try to compile it I get the error "type org.apache.wicket.datetime.markup.html.form.DateTextField does not take parameters" even though the Java docs show parameters on the constructor. I don't think the problem is in the form because it contains other textfields and labels and it works fine right now.

Also sorry if this is a stupid question, most other examples I found gloss over actually making the box and go into how to format it. I am very new to wicket and programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in JavaScript. There are a lot of JQuery plugins for this. First from Google Search:
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo

Here there are more:
http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/mask/

Doing it on wickets side is possible but an overkill if you ask me.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've never used JavaScript but apparently DateTextField is outdated, simply using "DateField" instead of "DateTextField" will create a textfield with a premade javaScript Calendar next to it that allows a date to be selected and will auto-fill with the correct format