# How to pretty print result of wicket validator

Tags: java, validation, wicket

I would like to include reformatting the field content in wicket field validation.

Example time input field:

User input: 1459 -> Validation is ok -> field displays reformatted value: 14:59 (with colon in the middle)

Thanks for any help,

uli

```
public class PhoneValidatorWrapper implements IValidator<String>, Serializable
{

    public PhoneValidatorWrapper()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(IValidatable<String> validatable)
    {
        // validation goes here ...
            // writing pretty print back to model
            validatable.getModel().setObject("hello world");            
    }
}
```

but still value displayed remains unchanged

Comment: Show your code. Give us something we can work on.

Comment: Normally you will have the field mapped to a Model. In this case, when you validate the data (server side) after submitting, you can just change the data in your model. But as Sebastian already stated, it would be easier if you showed the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use javascript that reformats the user input on the client side. The following jQuery plugin could probably do the job:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo

Also see:
[How to have users enter a formatted date in wicket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987818/how-to-have-users-enter-a-formatted-date-in-wicket)

Comment: nice solution but I already have the validators on server side from an existing library

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to do it:
it works by combining validator and behavior:

```
public class PhoneValidatorWrapper extends Behavior implements IValidator<String>, Serializable
{
    String prettyFormattedValue = null;

    public PhoneValidatorWrapper()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(IValidatable<String> validatable)
    {
        // validation goes here ...
        prettyFormattedValue = internalValidationResult.getPrettyValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeRender(Component component)
    {
        super.beforeRender(component);
        IModel defaultModel = component.getDefaultModel();
        defaultModel.setObject(prettyFormattedValue);
    }
}
```